# Is it bad practice to call a function from within another function and pass the same parameter twice? - Swift3

Tags: swift, conventions

I am new to iOS development and would just like to know if it is bad practice to do something along the lines of:

```
func bigFunc(){
    var parameter: String = "foo"
    firstFunc(parameter: parameter){

}

func firstFunc(parameter: String){
    let word: String = secondFunc(parameter: parameter)
    //do stuff with word
}

func secondFunc(parameter: String) -> String{
    return "bar"
}
```

Rather than just make the parameter a global variable and call both functions within bigFunc()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global variables should be avoided when possible. Best practice is to limit visibility of variables to the scope where they are needed, and if you make a global variable there it will be visible in the entire file—which risks variable name collisions and so forth.

If all three functions are actually members of a class, though, you could make it a property of the instance, if it makes sense for your "parameter" to be one.

Comment: This is not a global variable. As a matter of fact I agree with the way he wrote the functions since it makes it possible to easily implement test driven development.

Comment: Oh I hadn't thought of properties, since I've rarely touched them in Swift. Thanks!
Edit: Ah, indeed I am using TDD.

Comment: @Chiquis This answer does not claim that the question's code uses globals. The questions asks, at the end, if using globals would be better. This answer correctly points out that globals are not the correct solution. This answer basically points out that the code in the question is correct.